# How to write ASCII and BINARY data to the same file at the same time

Tags: c++, file-io, vtk, paraview

I work with a VTK data type for my outputs. Since my data is becoming larger and larger, it's taking considerable time to write it in ASCII and that's what I have been doing so far.

I need to change that into binary format but the problem is the file has some headers (see http://www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf) that need to be written in ASCII even for binary files.

Now I don't have enough experience with binary formats and my first try was to open two streams via

```
ofstream asciiWriter(file_name.c_str());
ofstream binWriter(file_name.c_str(), ios::app | ios::binary);
```

problem is the output seems to be disorganized and `asciiWriter` and `binWriter` are not outputting in the correct order and so I cannot post-process my file in ParaView. One thing I tried was to use `asciiWriter.flush()` and `binWriter.flush()` whenever I'm done with header/data writing but that does not help either.

What should I do?

PS: I do not want to use the VTK package itself ... its HUGE and adds to my code dependency!

Comment: ASCII *is* binary. What is the question?

Comment: I read part of the PDF file you linked to and I see what the problem is, yes. They do act as if ASCII is something different from binary. But don't let them fool you, just use one writer (with `ios::binary`) and you're OK.

Comment: @MrLister Thank you so much. I was confused and thought they are essentially two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On all modern systems that I know of, the only difference between binary and text files is the treatment of newlines and end-of-file characters by the C runtime library.  Specifically, on *nix systems, text and binary files behave exactly the same.  On Windows, writing a `'\n'` to a text file causes a `'\r'` (CR) followed by a `'\n'` (LF) to be written to the actual file; reading a `"\r\n"` pair shows up as a single `'\n'`.  Also on Windows, reading a `'\x1A'` (Ctrl-Z, EOF) from a text file signals the end-of-file condition.  Binary files are read and written verbatim, with no conversion.

Reading your document, I notice that it specifies `'\n'` only (not `"\r\n"`) at the end of the lines.  That suggests that the correct approach is to read and write the header as a binary file, even on Windows.

As an irrelevant aside, some older systems (RSX-11 and VMS come to mind) had binary files that were wildly different, on disk, from text files.  They also supported record-based and indexed files directly in the OS.  However, they had modified versions of the `open()`, `fopen()` etc functions (and the equivalents in other languages) to handle the plethora of arguments that could be specified when opening a file.  On such a system, you had to use the correct file mode every time.